# Instabug Android SDK

Tags: android, instabug

I am using

```
new Instabug.Builder(this, "MY_INSTABUG_KEY").setInvocationEvent(InstabugInvocationEvent.SHAKE).build();
```

On each shake, Instabug message appears even if it is already visible. How can I limit the appearance of Instabug message ie if one message is visible then next message should not be invoked until the first one is on the screen.

Comment: Have you tried v4.0.8?

Comment: It shouldnt be happening with the latest version of instabug, 4.2.2 i believe

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to update Instabug SDK.
https://docs.instabug.com/v8.1/docs/android-sdk-8-1-migration-guide